Cancancan with custom where_condition syntax on specific tables/columns
Imagine the following setup:
ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :books, force: true  do |t|
    t.jsonb :tags
  end
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :read, Book, tags: user.tags
  end
end

Calling Book.accessible_by(ability, :read).to_sql would result in something like: SELECT books.* FROM books WHERE tags IN ("foo", "bar"). This behaviour is totally understandable and correct.
However, I'd like to achieve something like this:
If i try to access books.tags, I always want a Query looking like: SELECT * FROM books WHERE (tags @> '["foo", "bar"]').
I would like to make use of the Postgres Jsonb Operator available and build some kind of Intersection. Is it possible to somehow hook into the Gem and e.g. patch a Method where the conditions are built and where i do some kind of hardconding like: if model == X && column == y build the condition like this, else go back the default way.
I explicitly do not want to work with custom scopes like can :read, Book, Book.custom_scope(user.tags) due to the inability of merging Abilities when defined multiple times. I want to be able to use the hash syntax.
Is there any chance i can achieve this?

Just use a join table instead of wasting a bunch of effort on an anti-pattern. Trust me, you'll thank me later. https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/

I understand and appreciate your comment but my example is just a very basic one to grasp the problem. In my current environment I cannot change the basic setup I work with and need to find a way on how to get it to work. With a basic sql-scope everything works except that Abilities are not mergable. I like that feature long-term wise and I'd like to prep the code accordingly if somehow possible

If you're really stuck with an unchangable schema than ditch CanCanCan. It's a strange old relic from the days when DSL's were the hot new thing and an aweful design at everything but scaling down to blorgh applications. Use Pundit instead which is just plain old OOP instead.

I also cannot ditch CanCanCan. I am working in a huge Codebase with the given setting. There is no chance in making big changes like introducing new Gems for existing authorizations written already with CanCanCan. Please stick to the question asked without trying to suggest changes non related to the question itself.

Best of luck then. But you're really going to be on your own on this one. I wouldn't expect an answer.

Why not just do something like this:
can :read, Book, id: Book.where(user_json_tag_query).ids
